# ViewModel save selected value from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a dropdownlist  - difficult. This is a dropdonwlinst where the user can select a value(easy, hard) but the value is not saved to the database, if I select a value. The strange thing I also have Country list, and that value is saved to the database.And If I put the values by hand in the database - for difficult the values are shown in the view

ModelVIew:

```
public RouteViewModel()
        {
            Countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
            DifficultGrades = new List<SelectListItem>();

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to give it a name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int SelectedValue { get; set; }


        public int SelectedId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DifficultGrades { get; set; }
    }

 public class Difficult
    {
        [Key]
        public int DifficultId { get; set; }
        public string DifficultName { get; set; }       
        public virtual ICollection<Route> Routes { get; set; }

    }

public class Route
    {

        [Key]
        public int routeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? UserProfileID { get; set; }
        public int? CountryID { get; set; }
        public int? DifficultGradeID { get; set; }



        public virtual UserProfile userProfile { get; set; }
        public virtual Country country { get; set; }
        public virtual Difficult difficult { get; set; }
    }

 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(RouteViewModel routeViewModel )
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    var route = new Route();
                    UpdateRoute(route, routeViewModel);
                    db.Routes.Add(route);

                    db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
            }


            ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.countries, "Id", "country_name", routeViewModel.Id);
            ViewBag.DifficultId = new SelectList(db.difficulties, "DifficultId", "DifficultName", routeViewModel.Id);
            return View(new RouteViewModel());
        }
```

and the update method:

```
public void UpdateRoute(Route route, RouteViewModel routeViewModel  )
        {
            route.routeID = routeViewModel.Id;
            route.Name = routeViewModel.Name;
            route.CountryID = routeViewModel.Id;
            route.DifficultGradeID = routeViewModel.Id;

            // climb.country.country_name = ModelViewClimb.Name;

        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you really intend `routeViewModel.Id` to be assigned to three different values?

Comment: Thank you for your answare. But how to do it different? I can save the Countries, but not the Difficults. I realy dont know how to do it else.

Comment: Make the selected Ids part of the view model. I don't understand why you're using the viewbag at all. And what are these nondescript properties `SelectedValue` and `SelectedId` in the view model?

Comment: Can you show me what you mean, Thank you

Comment: Can somebody help me??